# Select TOP row in SQL and get 5 rows of end table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Mytable:

```
Acode | Aname 
1       ll
2       bb
3       aa
4       zz
5       ee
6       tt
7       gg
8       ss
```

```
SELECT TOP(3) * from mytable order by acode desc
```

Result:

```
Acode | Aname 
8       ss
7       gg
6       tt
```

But I need the output:

```
Acode | Aname 
6       tt
7       gg
8       ss
```

SQL code?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP(3) * from mytable order by acode desc) a ORDER BY accode`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if this is the best way, you may have to do a nested select.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(3) * from mytable order by acode desc
) a ORDER BY accode
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT TOP(3) * from mytable order by acode asc
```

or

```
SELECT TOP(3) * from mytable order by acode
```

because ORDER BY clause default orders in ascending mode and that's right what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If the [Accode] field is a UNIQUE KEY, this should work:

SELECT * FROM  mytable
 WHERE Acode > (SELECT MAX(Acode) - 5 FROM mytable)

Comment: agree, only works in UNIQUE continuous values, but is much more efficient given this circumstance with tons of rows.